# Why datas use glReadPixels read from GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and GL_BACK are different?

Tags: opengl

I have codes lide this:

```
void init()
{...
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorPattern);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorPattern);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,GL_RGBA,outputSize[0],outputSize[1]);
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthPattern);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthPattern);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, outputSize[0], outputSize[1]);
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &patternFrame);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorPattern);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthPattern);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
}
```

Then I draw something with GL_BLEND enabled both in main framebuffer `glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);`and framebuffer `glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);`
At last,read some data by `glReadPixels()`:

```
void display(){
     ...
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, Num);
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, patternFrame);
     glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
     float test[4];
     glReadPixels(20, 200, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, test);
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, Num);
     glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
     glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
     glReadPixels(20, 200, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, test);
```

I find the data from all rgba chanel of patternFrame and framebuffer 0 is diferent.The alpha chanel of patternFrame is a fraction between 0 and 1, and constant 1 in main framebuffer.Why this happened?

Comment: Most likely, the default framebuffer has no alpha channel at all. Usually you can specify the format of the default framebuffer when the OpenGL window is created.

Comment: The values of the other channels can be slightly different depending on the internal format (bits) of the framebuffers.